# FedEx shipping is not showing up when check out for specific country

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping, fedex

I have added Puerto Rice to **'Ship to Specific Countries'** on **FedEx** Shipping config.
**US** and **Canada** are also on that list.

When I check out with **US** or **Canada**, It works perfectly

> But with **Puerto Rico**, It is not showing up.

Anything else I should do to solve it?

Thank for your help.

[image: FedEx Config]

[image: Check out]